# $y'=k+\sqrt{y},y(0)=0$ Prove $\forall k\neq0$ there is no solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=k+\sqrt{y},y(0)=0$

Prove $\forall k\neq0$ there is no solution.

My solution:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=k+\sqrt{y}\implies \frac{dy}{k+\sqrt{y}}=dx \implies \int\frac{dy}{k+\sqrt{y}}=\int dx \implies 2\left(\sqrt{y}-k\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{y}+k\right|\right)\right)=x+C$

The initial value is $(0,0)$ , hence $C=-2k\ln|k|$

The solution is $2\left(\sqrt{y}-k\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{y}+k\right|\right)\right)=x-2k\ln|k|$

I don't get why there is no solution.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: @TonyK fixed it

Comment: I believe the problem is mistake. For simplification $\sqrt{y}=u$. Take $k=1$. Then $y'(0)>0$, then domain of solution is $x\geq 0$ ($y$ must be non-negative. Then $2u-2\ln(u+1)=x$. This equation has positive solution for any positive $x$. Just plot $2u-\ln(u+1)$ and you'll see it.

Comment: If $y'(0)>0$ it doesnt stand with $y(0)=0$,no ?

Comment: No. Consider $y(x)=x$, then $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)>0$.

Comment: The only problem with existence of solution is shown by Robert Israel: rigor definition of derivative $y'(0)$ requires 0 to be in open subset of domain, which is not possible at $k\ne 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $y= 0$ (as at the point $x=0$), the differential equation says $y' = k \ne 0$.
Since $\sqrt{y}$ doesn't exist (as a real number) when $y < 0$, that means that a (real) solution can only be defined for $x \ge 0$ or $x \le 0$.  Since in order for a function to be differentiable at $x=0$ it must be defined in a neighbourhood of $0$ (including both positive and negative numbers), the differential equation is technically not defined at the initial point $y(0)=0$.

But that is really just a technical quibble: people solve differential equations all the time with initial conditions such as this, and it's interpreted as meaning: $y$ satisfies the differential equation for $x > 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0+} y(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is temporarily out of service.**

So if $k=0$, the IVP has solution $y(x)=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. If $k\not=0$, then the ODE $y'(x)=k+\sqrt{y(x)}$ is a Chini's equation and we can solve it for this special case as a separable equation and we get $-2k\ln|k+\sqrt{y(x)}|+2\sqrt{y(x)}=x+C$, with $C$ a constant of integration. Setting $y(0)=0$, we get the particular solution for the IVP as $y(x)=k^{2}\left(W\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{k^{2}}}ke^{-\frac{x}{2k}-1}\right)+1\right)^{2}$, where $W(\cdot)$ is Lambert W function.

Comment: You find a solution , the problem has a mistake ?

Comment: Yes, I found a solution but $W(z)$ is a real solution for $z\geqslant -\frac{1}{e}$. Now, study if it's possible for all $k\not=0$.

Comment: The first claim is wrong, for $x<0$ the square root has the wrong sign.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann thank you for you correction. I'm trying fix my answer. If I cannot, I will delete the answer. I just read it with sense $x>0$ for the initial condition. Do you think that all my answer is wrong? If that is, so I will delete all my answer. Not problem.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that the claim is based on the existence or non-existence of a solution on some interval $(-\delta,\delta)$. Solutions in the case $k=0$ are $\max(0,x-c)^2/4$ with $c\ge 0$. The other computation looks correct. It is interesting, additional information on the equation, but not overly relevant to the claim in question.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you for your response to my reply. So since my post does not answer the OP's question I will delete it if you agree. Hope you have a nice day!

Comment: I would only delete if irreconcilably wrong. My opinion should not be the yardstick to measure usefulness, the positive-votes reflect that more objectively.